# How to write formula in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to write out a formula that finds the max value that is greater than `12pm` and one formula that shows it as less than `12pm`.  I have one cell that shows `12:00:00PM` in order to do the less or greater than.  I have one column that shows timesteps and increment every 5 seconds (military time), and another column hat shows the data, this data column is where I need the max to be pulled from for AM time and PM time.

```
Cell A1= 12:00:00PM
```

`Cell A10:A20000= Timestep` starting at 0.0:00:00 and increments every 5 seconds so the next `cell A11` would be 0.0:00:05 when it hits noon it would be 0.12:00:00. Remember military time so when it hits `1pm` it would be 0.13:00:00.

```
Cell B10:B20000= data random numbers
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what exactly are you looking for ? it's not clear from the description.

Comment: You could use `AGGREGATE` > `=AGGREGATE(14,3,(A10:A20000<0.5)*B10:B20000,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the maximum value in column `B` where the timestamp is before 12:00 use:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,"<"&0.5)
```

For the maximum after 12:00, use:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,">"&0.5)
```

You can use `"<="` or `">="` to include 12:00, if needed

(note: `0.5` is 12:00, you can replace it with your cell if you want)

Comment: Note: You'll need either office 2019 or 365 to be using `MAXIFS`

Comment: Thank you, I ended up figuring this out, and I came up with a very similar formula to yours.